# What stands for `xxx.d` in home directory? daemon?

Tags: init.d

Like `emacs.d`, some programs have name like `xxx.d` for init files.
What does this `d` means? Is this abbreviation of something?

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason is it is easyest to copy a file to a directory, than to edit a section of a file.

see for instance : `/etc/logrotate.d`.

Thoses directories are used to store many configuration files, to allow automatic installer to deploy (or to remove) their own plugin/setting.